# Initwithframe UIScreen Mainscreen Bounds height is wrong ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscreen

I'm trying to initialize a custom view in a viewcontroller. My custom view has the following code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNib {
self = [super initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
if (self) {
```

The problem is, when I run it in emulator, the height is shorter than fullscreen. I am running it for iPhone 5s.

[image: height wrong image]

Why is this happening? I know there are a lot of posts where people talk about launch images and what not but I tried that for a little bit and still cant seem to get it to work. Can someone outline for me step by step exactly what I need to do? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

So I did a little more digging and in my Login ViewController, the self.view.bounds.size.height is 480 while the same attribute is 568 in the page where it looks weird. Why is this happening? How do I have it so the bounds are the same for the whole app?

**EDIT 2:**
I even added all the launch images of proper sizes and it still doesn't work. The size is still wrong.... someone please help!

Comment: Why you done like that?

Comment: How do you create the app's main window? I f you are doing a launch screen, just create a xib and set it as the launch screen in the project properties.

Comment: @Tapani, my launch screen is fine. This is a custom view I'm adding programmatically later on in another view controller

Comment: What do you mean by how am I creating the apps main window? Where would that be found?

Comment: You probably use a storyboard to initialize the main window then. Have your tried to set the custom view size to the view controller's root view's size not the main screen's size?

Comment: Oh that actually sounds like a promising idea. I will look into that in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: I made an edit in my post can yall take a look?

Comment: answer for me personally can be found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35353499/1819566